# Find shortest path in a matrix

Tags: c#, matrix, shortest-path

I have a matrix filled with 0 and 1 and I want to find the shortest between two points in the matrix passing only from zeros.
I found this [source code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9040/Maze-Solver-shortest-path-finder) which solves my problem but its only showing the result in the matrix by filling the path with the number 100 and I want to get the result in an array. Here is an example of a matrix :

```
0   0   0   1   0
0   1   1   1   1
0   0   0   0   1
1   1   1   0   0
```

My starting point is (0,0) and my target point is (4,3)
The program shows the result in this format :

```
100 0   0   1   0
100 1   1   1   1
100 100 100 100 1
1   1   1   100 100
```

But i want to get the result in this format :

```
(0,0), (0,2), (3,2), (3,3), (4,3)
```

Comment: Your link says it. It's a typical application of a "Breadth-First Search Algorithm" on a graph, which you have represented as a adjacency matrix. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search should give you an idea on how to solve this graph problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look at code below

```css
//create an array(maze) for solution
294              int[,] iMazeSolved=new int[iRows,iCols];
295              for(int i=0;i<iRows;i++)
296                  for(int j=0;j<iCols;j++)
297                      iMazeSolved[i,j]=m_iMaze[i,j];
298  
299              //make a path in the Solved Maze
300              iCurrent=iStop;
301              ChangeNodeContents(iMazeSolved, iCurrent, iPath);
302              for(int i=iFront; i>=0; i--)
303              {
304                  if (Queue[i]==iCurrent)
305                  {
306                      iCurrent=Origin[i];
307                      if (iCurrent==-1)       // maze is solved
308                          return ( iMazeSolved );
309                      ChangeNodeContents(iMazeSolved, iCurrent, iPath);
310                  }
311              }
​
```

iMazeSolved is the array containing the solution.  ChangeNodeContents is the solution after the path is replace with 1000's.  You just need the array iMazeSolved.